# Scala - How to write nested for comprehensions without returning Future of Futures in scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to do the following :

```
for {
    item <- createAnItem //createAnItem returns Future[Item]
        for (alphabet <- listOfAlphapbets) {
            for {
                a <- enterAlphabetsWithItem(alphabet.id, item.id) // enterAlphabetsWithItem returns a Future[NewAlphabets]
             } yield a
        }
} yield item
```

the problem is within the inner most `for` comprehension I get future or futures which is undesired. Is there a way to refactor this such that I do not get future of futures but am able to execute inner most `for` on every alphabet within the list?

Comment: `enterAlphabetsWithItem` returns a `Future`? Then there is not much you can do but wait for the `Future` to complete, returning the result.

Comment: Is this really valid Scala? Are you saying that it compiles but gives the wrong result, or that it does not compile?

Comment: @Tim it shouldn't compile, it's not valid Scala.

Comment: It compiles and gives a valid result. Problem arises when I try to put this in a mysql single transaction (using quill). Thats when future of futures makes a blocking call. 

What I am trying to figure is if there a way to get rid of inner most `for` or if I can use for each or something. If I have a single alphabet instead of listOfAlphabets (ie not a seq/ list but a single element), this is not a problem at all. Looping is making me add another inner `for`

Comment: Why do you generate (`<-`) an `a`, and then `yield` it, and then throw it away?

Comment: @ThatNewGirl [It does not compile.](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/qDl3J8D/0) Please proove otherwise.

Comment: @MarkusAppel look at the worksheet you provided, I modified it to what I had. Also found a solution to my problem. I removed the first `for` and let it stay as future and assigned to a val. then did the mapping within inner `for`. That way I don't get Future within future.

Thanks all for the inputs.

Comment: @ThatNewGirl; Please post the resolution you've found. (You are allowed to answer your own questions.)

Answer (score 0):

consider createItem returns Future[Item]

consider listOfAlphabets returns List[String]

enterAlphabetsWithItem  returns Future[String]

Then the simple solution would be

```
Future[String] resultFuture = createItem(input).flatMap(item => Future.sequence(listOfAlphabets.map(alphabet => enterAlphabetsWithItem(item, alphabet))))
```

`Future.sequence` converts `List[Future[X]]` to `Future[List[X]]`.